# How to draw a DC motor in circuitikz

Tags: symbols, circuitikz

I'm using `circuitikz` to create an electric circuit diagram. I'd like to draw a DC motor like this:

[image: DC motor symbol]
<sub>(source: [expertsmind.com](http://www.expertsmind.com/CMSImages/2198_DC%20Motor%20Connections.png))</sub>

or this one:

[image: IEC symbol for DC motor]

It looks like there's no symbol for motors in `circuitikz`. I'm using `\begin{circuitikz}[american]`. How I draw those symbols?

Comment: I have a tutorial on the subject: http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm and I also am willing to help.  Which of the above to you prefer?

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is to modify an existing two-terminal element in the `circuitikz` such as `sV` and redefine a new command called `\mymotor` that draws the desired shape and form.  Here two shapes (\mymotor, \mymotorB) are defined as asked by the OP.

```
\newcommand{\mymotor}[2] % #1 = name , #2 = rotation angle
{\draw[thick,rotate=#2] (#1) circle (10pt)
 node[]{$\mathsf M$} 
++(-12pt,3pt)--++(0,-6pt) --++(2.5pt,0) ++(-2.8pt,6pt)-- ++(2.5pt,0pt);
\draw[thick,rotate=#2] (#1) ++(12pt,3pt)--++(0,-6pt) --++(-2.5pt,0) 
++(2.8pt,6pt)-- ++(-2.5pt,0pt);
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}  
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,positioning}

\newcommand{\mymotor}[2] % #1 = name , #2 = rotation angle
{\draw[thick,rotate=#2] (#1) circle (10pt)
 node[]{$\mathsf M$} 
++(-12pt,3pt)--++(0,-6pt) --++(2.5pt,0) ++(-2.8pt,6pt)-- ++(2.5pt,0pt);
\draw[thick,rotate=#2] (#1) ++(12pt,3pt)--++(0,-6pt) --++(-2.5pt,0) ++(2.8pt,6pt)-- ++(-2.5pt,0pt);
}

\newcommand{\mymotorB}[2] % #1 = name 
{\draw[thick] (#1) circle (12pt)
node[above=-3pt]{$\mathsf M$} ++(-8pt,-3pt)--++(15pt,0);
\draw[thick,dashed] (#1) ++(-8pt,-5pt)--++(15pt,0);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,2) to[L, l_=$L$, o-*] (2,2) to[sV, color=white, name=M1] (3.5,2) to[short,*-] (5,2);
\mymotor{M1}{0}
\draw (0,0) to[short, o-*] (2,0) to[short, -*] (3.5,0) to[short] (5,0);
\draw (2,2) to[C=$C$] (2,0);
\draw (3.5,2) to[R=$R$] (3.5,0);
\draw (5,2) to[sV, color=white, name=M2] (5,0);
\mymotor{M2}{90}
%
\draw (2,3) to[sV, color=white, name=M3] (3.5,3);
\mymotorB{M3}

\draw (6,2) to[sV, color=white, name=M4] (6,0);
\mymotorB{M4}

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The hard part was getting the M right side up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\margins{0.2cm}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}
\screensize{3cm}{5cm}
\backgroundcolor{white}

% prepare to create bipoles

\makeatletter
\def\TikzBipolePath#1#2{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{#1}{#2}}
\def\CircDirection{\pgf@circ@direction}

\pgf@circ@Rlen = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}

\makeatother 

\newlength{\ResUp} \newlength{\ResDown}
\newlength{\ResLeft} \newlength{\ResRight}

% set default motor size

\ctikzset{bipoles/motor/height/.initial=.8}
\ctikzset{bipoles/motor/width/.initial=.8}

% create motor shape

\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}
 {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/motor/height}}
 {motor}
 {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/motor/height}}
 {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/motor/width}}
 {
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfextractx{\ResRight}{\northeast}
    \pgfextracty{\ResUp}{\northeast}
    \pgfextractx{\ResLeft}{\southwest}
    \pgfextracty{\ResDown}{\southwest}

  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.775\ResLeft}{0.2\ResDown}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\ResLeft}{0.2\ResDown}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\ResLeft}{0.2\ResUp}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.775\ResLeft}{0.2\ResUp}}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0.8\ResRight}{0cm}}
    {\pgfpoint{0cm}{0.8\ResUp}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.775\ResRight}{0.2\ResDown}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\ResRight}{0.2\ResDown}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\ResRight}{0.2\ResUp}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.775\ResRight}{0.2\ResUp}}
  \pgfusepath{draw} %draw motor
    \pgftext[rotate=-\CircDirection]{\textsf{M}}
 }

% create motorto-path style

\def\motorpath#1{\TikzBipolePath{motor}{#1}}
\tikzset{motor/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\motorpath, l=#1}}

% end of setup

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) to[motor, l=motor, o-*] (0,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\newpage
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) to[motor, l=motor, o-*] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```