# CircuiTikZ: Understanding the placement options of to[...]

Tags: circuitikz

Following-up [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514356/2288), for the following MWE, why does `to[short, name=motor1, pos=0.25]` draw the motor midway and not place it at the end of the first 1/4 of the path ?

Additionally, is there an option of `to[...]` to control the placement of the motor instead of doing it manually as I did twice below?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to[short, name=motor1, pos=0.25] ++(4,0);
        \draw (motor1) node[elmech](M1){M};

        \draw (0,-2) to[short, name=motor2] ++(4,0);
        \draw ([xshift=-1cm]motor2) node[elmech](M2){M};

        \draw (1,-4) node[elmech](motor3){M};
        \draw (0,-4) to[short] (motor3.west);
        \draw (motor3.east) to[short] (4,-4);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you like to do should be exception. So if you like to have them, than you set this exception manually. All dipoles are in middle of path between coordinates.  Why you like to change this?

Comment: @Zarko I just wondered why it accepted `pos=0.25` without considering its effect.

Comment: This can say authors of package. It seems that dipoles positions are hard coded to be in the middle of the path.

Comment: I was surprised it didn't rotate the contacts to match leads.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132076/how-to-draw-a-dc-motor-in-circuitikz/132300?r=SearchResults&s=1|55.0593#132300

Comment: @JohnKormylo the element `elmech` is a node-type element, so you have to rotate it manually. `Telmech` is a bipole-type. And no, `pos` is not useful here; the name is assigned to the bipoles `short` which is always placed in the center of the subpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `pos` is supposed to decide the placement of the component. The bipoles are drawn at the middle. Alternate way is using

```
    \draw (0,-2) -- ++(4,0)node[pos=0.25](motor2){};
```

Yes. Motor can be placed with `to[Telmech]`. Note that the name starts with T.

```
    \draw (0,-4) to[Telmech=M, name=M3] ++(4,0);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}

        \draw (0,0) to[short, name=motor1, pos=0.25] ++(4,0);
        \draw (motor1) node[elmech](M1){M};

        \draw (0,-2) -- ++(4,0)node[pos=0.25](motor2){};
        \draw (motor2) node[elmech](M2){M};

        \draw (0,-4) to[Telmech=M, name=M3] ++(4,0) to[Telmech=M] ++(0,-3);         
        \draw (M3.east) -- ++(0,-1);

    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me why the motor terminals weren't rotated properly to match the wires in the first two examples unlike the third one?

Comment: @Diaa in first two examples, the motor is placed as a node without rotation. But when it is done with `to[...]`, the node is rotated to align with the direction of the path.